# How to store array in firebase using Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, angular-datatables

I need to store Array in Firebase using Angular. I am not able to achieve this. Kindly please help.
What I am getting is this: 
[image: What I am getting]

what I want is this:

```
-|bucketList
    |-zjSaw3efefsfsdffg
       0-| bItem: 'thailand'
         | isCompleted: false

       1-| bItem: kasar devi
         | isCompleted: false
```

and so on

I am doing this:

```
 const bucketRef = this.angularFireDb.list('/bucketList/' + uid );
 bucketRef.push(bucketListItems);
```

Comment: Can you share the content of the `bucketListItems` object please.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec yes. I am sending an object `{bItem: this.bucketListItem, isCompleted: false}` 
and this.bucketListItem is dynamic i.e. comes from user

Comment: So you are pushing object by object, not as an that contains several `{bItem: this.bucketListItem, isCompleted: false}`. Since you push an object called `bucketListItems` **with an s** I thought maybe you push a list of objects (even if the ids of each object does seem to come from an individual push).

Comment: actually, the functionality is such that I've to push 1 object at a time and it should update in database with each push like `0 1 2 ....`
is this possible ? @RenaudTarnec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried somethings and figured out something. Posting it so that it can help anybody looking for same thing.

In my component, I am first pushing the object in an array and then sending that array to the service

```
      this.bucketListArray.push({bItem: this.bucketListItem, isCompleted: false});
      this.authService.saveUserBucketListInDb(this.bucketListArray);
```

In my service what I am doing is:

```
saveUserBucketListInDb(bucketListItems: Array<object> ) {

this.angularFireDb.object('/bucketList/' + uid).set({
  bucketListItems
});
```

}

which ultimately gave me what I was looking for i.e.: 
[image: Array stored in database]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By using [`push()`](http://itemsRef.set('key-of-some-data',%20%7B%20size:%20newSize%20%7D);) you generate a new node with an id that is automatically generated by Firebase (`-Lz6G...`).

If you want to write a node with an id that you generate (`0`, `1`, `2` in your case) you will have to use the [`set()`](http://itemsRef.set('key-of-some-data',%20%7B%20size:%20newSize%20%7D);) method.

The problem you may encounter in your case (since you create  objects like `{bItem: this.bucketListItem, isCompleted: false}` **one by one**) is that you don't know what is the last id present in the database. So you will have to query the database to find the value of the last id and increment it (preferably through a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions)).

Or, if you are able to create the objects in one batch using an array of objects, as follows, the node ids will follow the `0`, `1`, `2` sequence.

You can try the following:

```
  var bucketListItems = [
    { bItem: 'Item1', isCompleted: false },
    { bItem: 'Item2', isCompleted: false }
  ];

  const bucketRef = this.angularFireDb.list('/bucketList/');

  bucketRef.set(uid, bucketListItems);
```

Comment: `this.angularFireDb.object('/bucketList/' + uid).set({ 0: bucketListItems});` if I do something like this, then it works for only 1 item. which means, if i do 
`this.angularFireDb.object('/bucketList/' + uid).set({1: bucketListItems});` then it will overwrite the existing one.

Comment: And what if you do `this.angularFireDb.object('/bucketList/' + uid + '/0').set(bucketListItems);` and then `this.angularFireDb.object('/bucketList/' + uid + '/1').set(bucketListItems);`?

Comment: I tried something and it worked which kind of saved me the hassle of keeping track of the iteration. I have posted the answer. Please check and Thank you.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are using an array to save the different bucketListItems